# pip prints trash messages in stdout

Tags: python, linux, amazon-ec2, pip, boto

When I try to use pip commands, annoying messages are coming out in stdout:

```
~# pip -V
Platform: linu
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

~# pip install
Platform: linu
You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")
```

Python commands are working normally.

OS - Ubuntu 14.04

I tried to reinstall pip and all dependencies, but it didn't help.

What is that and where it comes from?

The problem was noticed when I tried to use ec2.py dynamic inventory script for AWS. I faced the same problem as here:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/14667

ec2.py generates JSON with starting "**Platform: linu**" and therefore ansible doesn't work with that.
Also I searched for boto library (used in ec2.py) and pip configs. But they are blank.

Any suggestions?

---

### Python

```
~# python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> print os.name
posix
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Linux'
```

Found one more way to reproduce the issue:

```
:/usr/bin# python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> import os
>>> import boto
Platform: linu
>>>
```

Comment: maybe it is problem in system configuration - check `uname -a`

Comment: No. It's ok
~# uname -a
Linux ip-*-*-*-* 3.13.0-68-generic #111-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:06 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: as for me python gets this information from system but I don't have access to my linux at this moment to check it.

Comment: btw: you have very old `pip`. The newest is `8.1.2` and you can install it using `pip install --upgrade pip` or shorter `pip install -U pip`. There is unoffical repository with the newest Python for Ubuntu [Python 2](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes-python2.7), [Python 3](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes)

Comment: It's newly installed pip. Old one with the same bug was 8.1.2 version. No difference.

Comment: when I run `pip` on Linux Mint (based on Ubuntu 14.04) I don't have line with `Platform:` :/ Try `python -m pip -V` . Do you get  `Platform` ?

Comment: when I run pip on any other system, it's all fine and there are no that stupid line with "Platform: linu" :(
python -m pip -V ## prints the same

Comment: I have no idea. I don't have EC2 to check it. Send problem to AWS admins. It seems some problem only with AWS Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This is common mistake. Most of this weird problem occur (whether in a plain PC,  VM or inside cloud instance such as EC2. Did you notice AWS EC2 using a different locked down pip version) is running Python in sudo mode.

> **DO NOT run PIP in sudo mode!**

My suggestion : [setup Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/) and install your package on that virtualenv.  Then use `mkvirtualenv yourenv` to create an custom virtualenv. 
To load a python script automatically with the designated virtualenv, you just need to put an extra line inside your bash script to trigger your python package/modules.

```
source <virtualenv_folder>/<virtualenv_name>/bin/activate
```